# Drag & Drop applying a negative position

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a drag & drop where when you drag the object into the droppable area the object is given the movement movement you made into the negative area as a negative positioning.

For the purpose of illustrating this, I've put together this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdcutter/1drbbfz5/) where you can drop a cute dog into the landscape provided to illustrate my issue. Code used below:

```
//DRAG & DROP
$(document).ready(
    function() {
      var a = 3;
      $('.drag').draggable({
        revert: 'invalid',
        cursor: 'move',
        //containment: '#drop',
        start: function(event,ui) { $(this).css("z-index", a++)}
      });

      $('#drop').droppable({
        accept: ".drag",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          console.log(this);

          //$(this).addClass('dropped'),
          $(this).append(ui.draggable);
        }
      });
});
```

I've done a good deal of reading on her about methods to correct this issue, many of which seem to belong to containment variable errors, but sadly I've had no lucky implementing those fixes to my own setup here. One thing to note is that I am using HTML2CANVAS to export shots of this #drop area so I have to make sure that the moved item is physically in the space. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/arj_dev/f7fzwpkL/1/) what you want?

Comment: In the sense that the dog stays visible, yes. The issue with that result is that the dog is staying in the original space code wise and not being inserted into the #drop space. Without being physically into the drop space the HTML2CANVAS I mentioned won't capture its image.

Comment: if you want to draw it on canvas after dropping then you can detect the mouse coordinate on the canvas and then draw the image on the canvas at that position from **drop** event handler. If this is what you want then i can try a fiddle.

Comment: That sounds like the desired result. If you've got a moment to fiddle, give it a shot. I'll try some options on my end regarding that concept as well.

Comment: okay i didn't get time then, here is the new [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arj_dev/f7fzwpkL/2/). Its a proof of concept, you have to fine tune it. I advice you to read about canvas element. For example the size of the canvas element should be given as attribute and not in css. And also you have to draw the background of the canvas using **context.drawImage**.You have to optimise the html and css so that the coordinate calculation for the drop is accurate.for this avoid too much nesting in the dom. check it, i will post it as answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update; I was able to solve this by forcing an absolute positioning. Not responsive, but I'm not 100% sure I need it to be for this instance.